# Is there any way to append data to existing GVariant dictionary?

Tags: glib, gio

I use GSettings to store my application settings. Format of these is "a{q(bsyssbyqqqq)}", so it is Dictionary.

Sometimes I need to add new record to that dictionary. I can retrieve it from GSettings as GVariant. Is there any way to just add one record?

I have created new GVariantBuilder to create that new entry and it works OK but result of its operation is just one record. To add all remaining I need to iterate over all existing dictionary entries and add them to the builder. Is there any simplier and more efficient way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably too late, but just for the record, glib documentation (http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.32/glib-GVariant.html) says:

> **GVariant** instances always have a type and a value (which are given at
>   construction time). The type and value of a **GVariant** instance can
>   never change other than by the **GVariant** itself being destroyed.

Therefore it is not possible to change (add some record to your dictionary) **GVariant**. The only way to do what you want is exactly what you are doing now.